# how to save collapsible button state to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 collapsible buttons that I want to save so it stays open/closed when they reload website

[Exaple website](https://adamexample.github.io/example1/)

How can I make it save if it is open or closed in local storage? I would really appreciate if someone could show me some code that would do that
here is the code

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="collapsible" class="collapsible">collapsible1</button>
<div class="content">
text1
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">collapsible2</button>
<div class="content">
text2
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Example iframe</button>
<div class="content">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ThiCMd5kGbE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Use localStorage.setItem(key, value) and localStorage.getItem(key).

Answer (score 1):

And heres a working example

```
const ls = localStorage;

// Loads when the document is ready
(() => {
    // Find all elements with the class .collapsible
    document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible').forEach(o => {
        // Add click event listener
        o.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Toggle the .active class
            o.classList.toggle('active');

            // Find the sibling element
            let content = o.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                // Remove the max height
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
                // Save the state to local storage using the elements id as key
                ls.setItem(o.getAttribute('id'), false);
            }
            else {
                // Set the max height
                content.style.maxHeight = `${content.scrollHeight}px`;
                // Save the state to local storage using the elements id as key
                ls.setItem(o.getAttribute('id'), true);
            }
        });

        // Check the local storage for the "state" using the elements id
        if (ls.getItem(o.getAttribute('id')) === 'true') {
            // Add the .active class to the element
            o.classList.add('active');
            // Find the sibling element and set the max height
            let content = o.nextElementSibling;
            content.style.maxHeight = `${content.scrollHeight}px`;
        }
    });
})();
```